# Generic Where Clause Ambiguity with Associated Types in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, where-clause, associated-types

I was writing some example code in a playground and wanted a function that returns the distance between two values, both of which conform to the Strideable protocol in Swift so that I could use the `distance(to other: Self) -> Self.Stride` function. My implementation was as follows:

```swift
func distanceFrom<T: Strideable, U>(_ a: T, to b: T) -> U where T.Stride == U
{
    return a.distance(to: b)
}
```

After observing this function for a while, I realized that I wasn't sure which Stride was being used in the where clause, the one from `a` or from `b`. From what I understand it would be possible for `a` and `b` to define different associated types for `Stride`. Also I haven't made any statements to ensure that a.Stride == b.Stride, although I understand that I could expand my where clause to do so.

So, which one would get used to check equivalence to `U`? To be clear, the question isn't about this particular code block, but rather any situation in which this ambiguity would exist.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are the same type. If you wanted them to be different `Strideable` types you would add another generic parameter conforming to `Strideable` such that the function signature appears as follows:

```
func bar<T: Strideable, V: Strideable, U>(_ a: T, to b: V) -> U where T.Stride == U, V.Stride == U {
  return a.distance(to: a) //Trivial return statement (see explanation below)
}
```

Although the aforementioned code would compile, `return a.distance(to: b)` would not compile because they (`a` and `b`) are different types and the definition of `distance` in Swift3 is `public func distance(to other: Self) -> Self.Stride` (note the use of `Self` which restricts `other` to the same type as the `Strideable` upon which this function is called).  In conclusion, although you could make `a` and `b` different types, for your application it would not make sense to do so.

As further evidence for not being able to call your original posted code with different types please see the attached 
[Playground screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bE1p.png) which shows an error when using different types.

However, this works fine in the playground.

```
func distanceFrom<T: Strideable, U>(_ a: T, to b: T) -> U where T.Stride == U {
  return a.distance(to: b)
}


let doubleFoo: Double = 4.5
let intFoo: Double = 4

let g = distanceFrom(doubleFoo, to: intFoo) // gives me a double of -0.5
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I believe that a and b would both conform to the Strideable protocol, but they could be different types. I've tested calling this function with a being an Int and b being a Double and it compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: Please try again using the screenshot and code snippet I added to my answer.  I believe they (both of the T's) must be the same type.